# tensorflow importing images correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/

been following this tutorial, my code is almost exact, with slight modifications.

the code works great and is almost always correct, except if i draw a new image it often fails, i assumed sample size was too small, but even if i copy paste a picture from the training material i still get a wrong result.

here is my current code :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import PIL

print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(x_train[0],cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
'''

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)  # scales data between 0 and 1
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)  # scales data between 0 and 1


def train():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()  # a basic feed-forward model
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())  # takes our 28x28 and makes it 1x784
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))  # a simple fully-connected layer, 128 units, relu activation
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))  # a simple fully-connected layer, 128 units, relu activation
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))  # our output layer. 10 units for 10 classes. Softmax for probability distribution

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',  # Good default optimizer to start with
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  # how will we calculate our "error." Neural network aims to minimize loss.
                  metrics=['accuracy'])  # what to track

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)  # train the model

    val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)  # evaluate the out of sample data with model
    print(val_loss)  # model's loss (error)
    print(val_acc)  # model's accuracy

    model.save('model',save_format='tf')

def predict():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')       
    img = Image.open('tests/num.png')                                                                                    
    img = np.resize(img, (28,28,1))                                                                                      
    im2arr = np.array(img)                                                                                               
    im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,1,28,28)                                                                                   
    y_pred = model.predict(im2arr)       
    print(np.argmax(y_pred))                                                                                             
    print(y_pred) 
  
predict()
```

replace predict() with train() to create the model, then edit it back and run the script

Comment: You normalized the training and testing sets, but you did not normalize the new images, no wonder the predictions are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make accurate predictions, you need to give the model data similar to what it has learned from. In this case, you used a normalizing function on your training data, and so the network has learned on data with float values between 0 and 1. So, you'll need to do the same treatment to the data you're trying to predict from.

```
im2arr = np.array(img) 
im2arr = tf.keras.utils.normalize(im2arr, axis=1)
```

Comment: if i replace im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,1,28,28)  i get this error ```ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 28]
```, and if i keep it but also put in the line you suggested nothing changes

Comment: normalizing it as you did, didnt change anything and removing im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,1,28,28) throws me an error

Comment: Normalizing the input will not change anything except provide better results, which is what you were after.

Comment: they are still very wrong tho, and it seems like for every time i make a new model it gets fixated on one of the numbers and always predicts that one, no matter what it is i input